# Is there a categorical impertaive against humour?

Tags: kant, practical-ethics, categorical-imperative

I understand it in the formulation: will only whatever you can will for everyone without [logical] contradiction.

If everyone kept telling jokes after a bit nothing would be funny.

So do we have an perfect duty not to tell jokes?

Comment: learning exercise sorry

Comment: Haha there is around this place!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not convinced that hearing jokes all the time would make them not funny. As long as they are original there does not need to be a problem. There's also no reason to assume we'd run out of original jokes.

But if we'd assume that hearing jokes all the time implied that they wouldn't be funny anymore, then yes, the categorical imperative in that formulation tells you to never tell jokes.